# d3 Multi Series Chart with Incorrect Values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to implement the d3 multi-series line chart example at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955.

But I'm having a problem when using my own data - as the lines don't seem to match the legend/ values in the JSON data. For example at 10:00, the "high" line should be measuring 3512 "threats" on the y-axis.

```
city.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); }) // Problem here?
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

Please take a look at this js fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/Ca8Uj/

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this behaviour because you're using the *basis* [interpolation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_interpolate) on your lines, which smooths out peaks (ie the line is not guaranteed to go through each point).

If you change to:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")
```

You should see the correct values. Alternatively to get a smooth-ish line that shows correct exact y-values you could use `monotone`. To experiment with interpolations, have a look at: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4342190

Comment: Ah that's great. Thank you so much. I obviously have a lot to read up on! Cheers!